# Map to Deedle Frame

Tags: dictionary, f#, dataframe, deedle

I am learning F#. 
I am trying to convert a `Map<string, seq<DateTime * float>>` to a Deedle dataframe (http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/tutorial.html#creating).

I have prapared the following code:

```
let folderFnct (aFrame:Frame) colName datesAndValues =
    let newSerie = Series(Seq.map (fun x -> fst x) datesAndValues, Seq.map (fun y -> snd y) datesAndValues)
    let newFrame = aFrame.Join([colName], [newSerie], kind=JoinKind.Inner)
    newFrame


let mapToDeedleFrame myMap frame =       
    Map.fold ( fun s ticker datesAndValues -> folderFnct s ticker datesAndValues) frame myMap
```

`mapToDeedleFrame` folds the map using an existing frame. The folder function `folderFnct`:

- takes the frame
- uses the Map key as column name in the frame, and
- processes the values (`<DateTime * float>`) making a Series of them.

The problem is with:

```
let newFrame = aFrame.Join([colName], [newSerie], kind=JoinKind.Inner)
```

where:

> The field, constructor or member 'Join' is not defined

**I have identified three potential causes of the issue:**

1. Why is `aFrame.Join` not defined? I tried explicitly specifying the type of `aFrame`
2. How can I feed to `mapToDeedleFrame` an **empty** frame?
3. Should I pattern match in `folderFnct` against the case where `aFrame` is empty?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1**

Based on Tomas suggestion, this is what I have cranked out so far.

```
let folderFnct (aFrame:Frame<'a, 'b>) columnName (seqOfTuples: seq<'a*'b>) =
    let newSerie = Series(Seq.map (fun x -> fst x) seqOfTuples, Seq.map (fun y -> snd y) seqOfTuples)
    let otherFrame = Frame([columnName], [newSerie])
    let newFrame = aFrame.Join((otherFrame), kind=JoinKind.Inner)
    newFrame


let mapToDeedleFrame myMap frame =       
    Map.fold ( fun state k vals -> folderFnct state k vals) frame myMap
```

The last step missing is: how do I quickly pass an empty Frame (maybe avoiding creating a dummy one) to `mapToDeedleFrame`? I have tried `[]` as in

```
let frame = mapToDeedleFrame mapTS []
```

This may be a silly question, but I am new to F# and I was wondering if there is an `Empty` type built in the language.

**FOLLOW UP QUESTION**

In the source file I read (https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/master/src/Deedle/Frame.fs):

```
  member frame.Join<'V>(colKey, series:Series<'TRowKey, 'V>, kind, lookup) =    
    let otherFrame = Frame([colKey], [series])
    frame.Join(otherFrame, kind, lookup)
```

while in the function description popping out on the screen:

[image: Printscreen]

From the picture above I would guess that the type of the Frame is the same as colKey, while, as I understood, colKey is just the key to the dataframe column added with the join from the serie. As a complete noob, I am quite confused..

**EDIT 2**

I have rewritten the code:

```
let seriesListMapper (colName:string, series:Series<'a, 'b>) = 
    [colName => series] |> frame


let frameListReducer (accFrame: Frame<'a, 'b>) (aFrame: Frame<'a, 'b>) =
     accFrame.Join(aFrame, kind=JoinKind.Outer)


let seriesListToFrame (seriesList: List<string * Series<'a, 'b>>) =
    seriesList |> List.map (fun elem -> seriesListMapper elem) |> List.reduce(fun acc elem -> frameListReducer acc elem)
```

The problem is that:

```
let frame = seriesListToFrame seriesList
```

returns frame as Frame, while seriesList is instead `(string *Series<DateTime, float>) list`

I think that the problem is with:

```
let seriesListMapper (colName:string, series:Series<'a, 'b>) = 
    [colName => series] |> frame
```

In fact `seriesListMapper` is indicated as

```
seriesListMapper: colName:string * series:Series<'a, 'b> -> Frame<'a, string>
```

I do not understand how and why the values are converted to `string` from `float`.

One interesting thing is that plotting the frame with `frame.Format()` actually confirms that the data looks correct. It is just this "strange" conversion to `string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the type annotation of the `folderFnct`, you have `aFrame:Frame`. However, the type representing data frames is a generic type with two type arguments (representing the type of index for rows and columns, respectively), so the annotation should be `aFrame:Frame<_, _>`.

Another way to add series to a frame is to use mutating operation:

```
aFrame.AddSeries(colName, newSeries)
```

However, this only supports left join (data frame can only be mutated by adding new series, but not in a way that would change the index). However, you might be able to use this approach and then drop all missing values from the frame once it is constructed.

**EDIT**: To answer the question about generic types:

- `Series<K, V>` represents series with keys of type `K` containing values of type `V` (e.g. series with ordinarily indexed observations would have `K=int` and `V=float`)
- `Frame<R, C>` represents a frame that contains heterogeneous data (of potentially varying types for each column) where the rows are indexed by `R` and columns are indexed by `C`. For ordinarily indexed frame `R=int` and typically, your columns will be named so `C=string` (but you can have other indices too)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a follow-up Q: .. Sorry - I could not paste the Q here, I'll add that editing the main Q above ..

Comment: I added comment about the types and answered your other question.